# Firebase Real Time Database Validate Number Increment

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase Real-Time Database as backend.
I want it to increase by 1 max for each request
For example:

```
    "Counter":{
       ".write":"true",
       ".read":"true,
       ".validate":"data.val()+1"
    }
```

This is not working.

**On the frontend, I'm sending "data+1". How should i create ".validate" rules?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate that the new value is one higher than the existing value:

```
".validate":"newData.val() === data.val() + 1"
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [Existing Data vs. New Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data).

Comment: Thanks Frank. ".validate" not working but ".write":"newData.val() === data.val() + 1" working. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hmm.... I expect `.validate` to work too. Is there any error message (other than maybe `permission denied`)?

Comment: pardon. I just thought it wasn't working. It worked when I tried again. Thanks. I have benefited greatly from your answers in this post and other posts on Firebase topics.

Comment: Good to hear `.validate` worked after all Orhan. 